# $A-(B∩C)=(A−B)∪(B−C)$ proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How do I prove the following equality  $A-(B∩C)=(A−B)∪(B−C)$

Let $Y = A-(B∩C)$,     $Z = (A−B)∪(B−C)$

I know that by definition must be a double containment $Y ⊂ Z$ and $Z ⊂ Y$.

By drawing Venn diagrams, I believe that equality is not true. so I want to do a containment failure, in particular this $Z ⊂ Y$, and that this failure should deny the implication that says if $x∈Y$ then $x∈Z$ if I deny would be as follows; $x∈Y$ and $x∉Z$.

I've come this far but I have a crisis of creativity to continue, please any collaboration is the most grateful

Comment: I think it should be $A-(B \cap C) = (A-B) \cup (A-C)$. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Say $x \in A-(B \cap C)$
$$\Rightarrow x \in A \cap (B \cap C)^c$$
$$\Rightarrow x \in A \,\ \text{and} \,\ x \in (B \cap C)^c$$
$$\Rightarrow x \in A \,\ \text{and} \,\ x \not \in (B \cap C)$$
$$\Rightarrow x \in A \,\ \text{and} \left(\,\ x \not \in B \,\ \text{and} \,\ x \not \in C\right)$$
$$\Rightarrow \left(x \in A \,\ \text{and} \,\ x \not \in B \,\ \right)\text{or} \left(\,\ x \in A \,\ \text{and} \,\ x \not \in C\right)$$
$$\Rightarrow \left(x \in A - B \,\ \right)\text{or} \left(\,\ x \in A - C\right)$$
$$\Rightarrow x \in \left(A - B \right)\cup\left( A - C\right)$$

Similarly take $y \in \left(A - B \right)\cup\left( A - C\right)$ and prove that $y \in A-(B \cap C)$.
Then you will get that $Y$ is a subset of $Z$ and $Z$ is a subset of $Y$. So they are equal.

Answer (score 0):

In order to prove (or disprove)
$$ A\setminus (B\cap C) = (A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus C) \tag{1}$$
you may consider $8$ different cases, according to $x$ belonging or not to $A,B,C$.

For instance, if $x\in A,x\in B,x\not\in C$, then $x\not\in (B\cap C)$ and $x\in A\setminus (B\cap C)$. Since $x\in B\setminus C$, $x$ belongs to both the RHS and the LHS of $(1)$. Can you check all the other cases?

You may also notice that if $A,B,C$ are disjoint, the LHS of $(1)$ is $A$ while the RHS is $A\cup B$, hence if $B\neq\emptyset$ equality cannot hold.

Answer (score 0):

If you deem an inclusion such as $Z\subset Y$ false in general, you just have to consider a counterexample, that is, three *particular* sets $A$, $B$ and $C$ so that the inclusion is not true.

Hint: What happens if $A=\emptyset$, but $B-C$ isn't empty?

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$€$A-(B∩C)$

←→$x$€$A$ and $x$ doesn't € $(B∩C)$

←→ $x$€$A$ and $x$€ $(B∩C)'$

←→ $x$€$A$ and $x$€ $(B'$U$C')$

←→ $x$€$A$ and [$x$€$B'$ or $x$€$C'$]

←→ [$x$€$A$ and $x$€ $B'$] or [$x$€$A$ and $x$€$C'$]

←→ [$x$€$A$ & $x$ doesn't € $B$] or [$x$€$A$ & $x$ doesn't €$C$]

←→$x$€$(A-B)$ or $x$€$(A-C)$

←→$x$€$(A-B)$U$(A-C)$

Hence, $A-(B∩C)$=$(A-B)$U$(A-C)$

Comment: I keep a bookmark for http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference. Using mathjax properly does wonders for the reability of your posts.

Comment: @Paul Thanks  but I suspect it works equally well in mobile.

Comment: If your mobile device renders that poorly, I suggest upgrading to one built within the last decade. I'm only offered some advice on making your posts more readable. If you prefer to have your posts ignored because it just isn't worth it to wade though that. Go right ahead and continue as you have.